# Unable to get the correct .ascii sum

Tags: nasm

ok,I'm now on assembly.I was making some programms to understand how ascii,hex,binary and system calls works, but actually i came across this problem:
when i input 11(1+1) for example,b is the result and not 2. Why?

```
SECTION .bss:
    Num1: db 1
        Num2: db 1
    Ris db 1

Read:   
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,Num1
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,Num2
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov edx,[Num1] 
    mov ebx,[Num2]
    add ebx,edx
    mov [Num2],ebx

Write:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,Num2
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
```

and why if i input only num 1 and when I try to sum it in this way the result is correct?
when i input 1(1+3) for example,4 is the result and not d(how wold it have been in the first case). Why?

```
SECTION .bss    
    Num1: db 1
    Num2: db 1
    Ris db 1

    ;inpb: resb 1
SECTION .data

SECTION .text 
    global main

Read:   
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,Num1
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    ;  mov eax,3
    ;  mov ebx,0
    ;  mov ecx,Num2
    ;  mov edx,1
    ;  int 80h

    mov edx,[Num1] 
    mov ebx,3 ;rather than Num2 i put 3 

    add ebx,edx ;sum beetwen Num 1 and 3 
    mov [Num2],ebx


Write:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,Num2
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
```

Comment: When you read input from the user you get [ASCII](http://asciitable.com), right? So when you read `1` you are getting `0x31` (that's ASCII for `1`) and if you add two of those together you get `0x62` which is ASCII for `b`. Thus in your attempt to add 1+1 you get `b` on the output. When you read input you need to convert the ASCII value to a number, do your arithmetic, then convert the result back to ASCII to display to the user. Your title is a little confusing as it sounds like you are not wanting to get an "ascii sum" at all here.

Comment: In your second program you read in 1 as ASCII (thus, it's 0x31) then you literally add 3 to it giving 0x34, which is ASCII for the number 4. So when you display it to the user, you see a `4`.